# What are some performance-improving tips for Java?

Tags: java, performance, memory, ram

**Hey guys,**

I'm a relatively new programmer in Java(and in general), but I want to know different ways of minimizing memory and RAM usage in programs that I make. I've heard of a few such as `StringBuilder` as an alternative to `+` String concatenation and stuff, but I'd like to hear what you guys know about how to maximize performance and why.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: This question could produce several books--in fact, it has. Start with _Effective Java_ by Josh Bloch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern programming, it is a far better use of time your time to focus on making your code readable rather than trying to micro-optimse.

Modern compilers do an extremely impressive job of these small optimisations so that everyday programmers don't have to deal with them, and in the majority of cases it is better to leave it up to the compiler than to attempt it yourself.

In general I would say that the largest performance improvements can be gained by thinking about the design of your program ahead of time, before you even start typing. Once you've already bashed out 10,000+ lines of code implementing your latest 3D high-performance MMORPG, and you realise it's not as high-performance as you were hoping, making any drastic design changes will be considerable work. Some things to think about beforehand are:

- Think about your algorithms complexity, for example string concatenation can be O(n^2) using String, but O(n) using StringBuilder.
- Use [object pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) to reuse memory rather than creating new instances each time
- Reuse existing library implementations of data-structures etc, rather than trying to recreate them yourself. Many more man-hours will have been put into these implementations than you could possibly spend on them, and so they are likely to be more efficient/robust

Finally I should mention, that if you do go trying to optimise some existing code because its not performing as well as needed, it's very important to know specifically where the problem area is. In this case a profiler is invaluable, and should help pinpoint any particular areas that are affecting performance. They might not be where you expect!

Comment: If you're going to quote Knuth you should quote the entire sentence. It doesn't entirely support what you're state here. Taken by itself, the partial quotation is nonsense. You should certainly select efficient algorithms and data structures ahead of time rather than after the fact.

Comment: @EJP You're right, I've reworded a bit to hopefully be a little clearer.